# Error when writing a karma unit test for an angular controller that is on a module that has $httpProvider interceptor configurations

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a very simple controller:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("TestCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.value = 5;
        $scope.func = function () {
            return 10;
        };
    });
```

And I am about to start learning how to do unit tests using karma.. The problem is that myApp has those configurations - especially the last one:

```
angular.module("myApp",["ui.router", "blueimp.fileupload", "ui.bootstrap"]);
        .config(function( $locationProvider ) {
                    $locationProvider.html5Mode( true );
        })
        .config(function ($urlRouterProvider) { })
        .config(function ($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
               .state("blabla", { url : "someurl", templateUrl : "templatePath" });

       })
       .config(function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push("httpInterceptor");
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push("htmlTemplateCacheBuster");
       });
```

I started writing some test code ...

```
describe("TestCtrl", function($log) {
    "use strict";

    it("first test", function () {
        expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("myApp"));

    beforeEach(inject(function() {}));
});
```

Everything works fine but when I add the last line, trying to start injecting things I get this error.. I found out it has to do with the last config with $httpProvider..

```
e 44.0.2403 (Windows 7 0.0.0) TestCtrl first test FAILED
        Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: htmlTemplateCacheBusterProvider <- htmlTemplateCacheBuster <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$injector/unpr?p0=htmlTemplateCacheBusterProvider%20%3C-%20htmlTemplateCacheBuster%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateFactory%20%3C-%20%24view%20%3C-%20%24state
            at C:/Workspace/myApp/Dev/UI/app/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular.js:63:12
            at C:/Workspace/myApp/Dev/UI/app/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular.js:3994:19
            at Object.getService [as get] (C:/Workspace/myApp/Dev/UI/app/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular.js:4141:39)
            at C:/Workspace/myApp/Dev/UI/app/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular.js:3999:45
            at Object.getService [as get] (C:/Workspace/myApp/Dev/UI/app/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular.js:4141:39)
            at C:/Workspace/myApp/Dev/UI/app/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular.js:8777:23
            at forEach (C:/Workspace/myApp/Dev/UI/app/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular.js:323:20)
            at $HttpProvider.$get (C:/Workspace/myApp/Dev/UI/app/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular.js:8775:5)
            at Object.invoke (C:/Workspace/myApp/Dev/UI/app/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular.js:4182:17)
            at C:/Workspace/myApp/Dev/UI/app/lib/angular/1.3.9/angular.js:4000:37
Chrome 44.0.2403 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.028 secs / 0.015 secs)
```

If anyone could help me I would appreciate it! I am using Angular and Mocks v 1.3.9 and ui-router 0.2.13...

Thanks

Comment: You won't be testing state switching. ui-router has it's own tests. Rather implement tests for you controllers/directives that represent those states

Comment: @KirillSlatin well the problem is that the module has those configuration dependencies.. I don't want to test those I want to test the controller... If I comment out the last config of the module tests are able to work :/...

Comment: Where is the httpInterceptor service defined? What is this missing htmlTemplateCacheBuster service, and where and how is it defined? It seems you forgot to add a JS file in your karma configuration. But you should also use several submodules (and not just one app module), and only load the required module(s) into your test. The app configuration is usually useless in a unit test.

Comment: That is the reason.. Those two factories are also attached on the same module ```myApp```. I updated the code to be consistent. How can I fix that .. without needing to mock those etc..? I don't really care about anything except for the controller...

Comment: There should be no reason to mock them. But as I said, the best way to solve this is to avoid depending on them in the tests. Store you controller in a submodule (like 'controllers'), and only load that 'controllers' module in the test, rather than loading the app module.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right but the existing application is unfortunately very flat and everything under the same module.. :/ so that can't be changed now

Comment: Then add the necessary JS files to the karma configuration, or add files that define mock versions of the missing services. Or make the app more modular, and thus more testable.

Comment: @JBNizet adding one forgotten file in karma.conf.js that was not in the correct path pattern fixed the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: if you can formalize a detailed answer about what someone should make sure he has right about tests in general case when he sees problems like those, I could accept it - Like make sure it is in the karma.conf.js or make sure is on a loaded module etc..